# Spring boot - Issue in invoking Shutdownhook

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, shutdown-hook

When i try to shutdown the spring boot application using ctrl+c or using process id using below script.. Shutdown hook is not invoked. Require some solution to invoke the shutdown hook both in windows and linux.

Shutdown script:

```
 SET /P PID_FROM_FILE= < application.pid
 taskkill /pid %PID_FROM_FILE% /f
```

Gracefulshutdown hook class:

```
@Component
public class GracefulShutdownHook {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger   (GracefulShutdownHook.class);

@Autowired
@Qualifier("inboundChannel")
MessageChannel inboundChannel;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("pollingExecutor")
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pollingExecutor;

  @PreDestroy 
  public void onDestroy() throws Exception {
// First stop the file integration adapter to process files
  inboundChannel.send(new  GenericMessage<String> "@'filesInChannel.adapter'.stop()"));
//  wait till current processing of files is over
 pollingExecutor.shutdown();
 LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Application shutdown succesfully");
}
@Bean
public ExitCodeGenerator exitCodeGenerator() {
return () -> 0;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not handle `ctrl-c` nor `taskkill` inside your Spring application.

The one of ways you can *appropriately* shut down your application is to create endpoint `POST /shutdown` and call `applicationContext.close()` inside it:

```
@RestController
public class Shutdowner {

    @Autowired 
    ApplicationContext ctx;

    @PostMapping("/shutdown")
    public void shutdown(){
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

More examples can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown

Comment: Thank you for your reply..... Was able to invoke shutdown hook... But unable to print the log in predestroy method in grateful shutdown.... may be logger console is closed before...Can u suggest on this